# Scala Seq - How to solve overloaded method value with alternatives due to Seq

Tags: scala

I have a function as follows:

```
def foo(sequence: Seq): Unit = {
    ...
    bar.select(sequence);
}
```

I obtained an error, `overloaded method value select with alternatives`. I'm new to Scala's syntax, and I don't know the exact term, so I have been searching online without any results.

In particular, Scala appears to be confused as to which of the `select` method I am calling. From the documentation, there are 2 `select` methods (Source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

I have tried the following, but perhaps because I am not familiar with the syntax, I was not able to succeed:

```
bar.select(sequence.asInstanceOf[Seq[Column]]);
```

How do I tell Scala that I want it to use `select(cols: Column*)` instead of alternatives? And if it is fine, could the answer include what concept this is - just so I can tag it properly, and learn something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `foo` method like this and use `_*`. As shown below

```
def foo(sequence: Seq[Column]): Unit = {
    bar.select(sequence: _*)
}
```

Explanation `select` takes var args. When you want to pass `Seq` to a method which takes var args you have to explicitly say `_*` So that compiler can accept the `Seq` as var args.

**Scala REPL example**

```
scala> def foo(a: Int*) = 1
foo: (a: Int*)Int

scala> foo(Seq(1, 2))
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Int]
 required: Int
       foo(Seq(1, 2))
              ^

scala> foo(Seq(1, 2): _*)
res1: Int = 1
```

*notice calling `foo(Seq(1, 2)` gives a compilation error this error can be fixed if we guide the compiler by giving type explicitly as `_*`*

Comment: I got `error: reference to Seq is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by import scala.collection.mutable._
and import scala.collection.Seq`. Is there any way to resolve this? And would you happen to know what this concept this relates to?

Comment: @Stanley you have imported `Seq` twice .. so remove `import scala.collection.mutable._`

Comment: This seems to result in `error: reference to Seq is ambiguous;` when I tried the above. I tried `: _*` and it threw the above error.

Comment: @Stanley ... the problem is not with this code. Problem is some where in your code .. You have imported two types of `Seq` remove one. remove `import scala.collection.mutable._` or rename the mutable `Seq` like this `import scala.collection.mutable.{ Seq => MSeq}  `

Comment: @Stanley ... just remove this line from your code `import scala.collection.mutable._` and import mutable collections separately